# C# Button Text Condition

Tags: c#, xml, button

Using a WinApp form in c#, and many buttons here...

I want to create a condition, that if a button has text in it, then the background color of that button changes. That sounds easy enough to do. But what I have is a common set of buttons, that have text in them dependant of values in a XML document.

Example: Week 1 - Buttons 1, 3 and 5 have text in them. Week 2 - Buttons 2 and 3 have text.

How can I setup a seperate condition to check if the button has text in it or not, and then change the color if there is a text value in the button.

Thank you.

Comment: Let me extend a bit on my aim: In the XML document there is also a field called <Duration>. This might be just 1 button, or 2, or more. So when <Duration> = 2 Buttons I need it to color the first button with the text, and the next button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
foreach (var btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
  btn.BackColor = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(btn.Text)) 
                ? SystemColors.ButtonFace : Color.AliceBlue;
}
```

I would put it in a method, and call it on form load, or whenever the buttons' texts changes.

Answer (score 2):

I would extend button and override the label setter such that it also changes the color when setting the contents of the label to some non-empty value.